# Redirecting cmake output in C++ using CreateProcessW

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to redirect a program output in C++ on Windows using CreateProcessW.
When I try to use it to redirect the output of programs such as git it works fine but when I'm doing it with cmake I get the following message on the console instead:

```
Failed to create ConsoleBuf!
```

My code looks like that:

```
void Process::Start(const std::string &args) const
{
    HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd = nullptr;
    HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr = nullptr;

    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr;
    saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = nullptr;
    if (!::CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, &g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr, &saAttr, 0)
            || !::SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0))
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Error while creating pipe: " + GetLastError());
    }
    PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcInfo;
    STARTUPINFOW siStartInfo = { sizeof(STARTUPINFOW) };
    ::ZeroMemory(&piProcInfo, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
    ::ZeroMemory(&siStartInfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    siStartInfo.hStdError = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    siStartInfo.hStdOutput = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    siStartInfo.hStdInput = nullptr;
    siStartInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    std::string fullPath = (std::filesystem::path(_path) / _name).string();
    std::string fullArgs = " " + args;
    if (!::CreateProcessW(std::wstring(fullPath.begin(), fullPath.end()).c_str(),
                        const_cast<LPWSTR>(std::wstring(fullArgs.begin(), fullArgs.end()).c_str(),
                        nullptr,
                        nullptr,
                        TRUE,
                        0,
                        nullptr,
                        std::wstring(_path.begin(), _path.end()).c_str(),
                        &siStartInfo,
                        &piProcInfo))
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create new process: " + GetLastError());
    }
    ::CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hProcess);
    ::CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hThread);
    DWORD dwRead;
    TCHAR chBuf[BUFSIZ];
    BOOL success;
    do
    {
        success = ::ReadFile(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, chBuf, BUFSIZ, &dwRead, nullptr);
        if (success && dwRead > 0)
            std::wcout << chBuf << std::endl;
    } while (!success || dwRead == 0);
}
```

I tried searching on Google and I found it was about the implementation of std::cout that doesn't handle properly unicode characters, but I'm not sure how to fix that?

Comment: Sounds like maybe cmake doesn't support I/O redirection and requires its output to go only to a console.

Comment: You have `dwCreationFlags` set to 0 in your call to `CreateProcessW`. This makes the launched process inherit your program's console, which maybe isn't Unicode. Maybe you should try with `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Brecht Sanders said, changing the value of dwCreationFlags from 0 to CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE solved the issue.